# Как называются такие глаголы?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, грамматика

Сравните ниже по 2 формулировки одних и тех же мыслей:

- "*Пройдя* мимо я позвал собаку" - "Я прошёл мимо и позвал собаку";
- "*Поднимая* вверх взгляд я увидел красивое облако" - "Я поднял вверх взгляд и увидел красивое облако";
- "*Заведя* будильник лёг спать" - "Завёл будильник и лёг спать".

В какой-то момент обратил внимание, что есть преимущества у первых формулировок. Во-первых, такие глаголы помогают сократить речь, а, во-вторых, в таких случаях больше смыслового акцента придаётся вторым глаголам (позвал, увидел, лёг).

Как называется глаголы, выделенные курсивом?

И какая у них пунктуация? В моих примерах всё правильно?

Comment: Советую вам ознакомиться с материалом по ссылке: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part4#i9

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан? Если нет, могу ответить)

Comment: @ИгорьБолотов, да, это то, что я хотел. Можете написать ответ, я отмечу его.

Comment: @V.V., буду иметь в виду. Спасибо.